# RDBMS mapping for scenario considering EF 4.1 CF

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I can't seem to get my head around a comfortable solution for the following scenario:

- Client / server application where server prepares an examination package file.
- A package file is like a license for one examination session (one-to-one).
- Package file is downloaded by admin, fed into a desktop client where student will be going through his exam session.
- Client app records exam session, repackages the results for the admin to collect.

I am currently using TPT. The problem is I use an EDMX file to create the model, ignore the DB mapping, generate DbContext and POCO classes from customized templates and resume in a CF-friendly way from there as if the EDMX did not exist.

I cannot visualize how to structure these classes. Both the server and client package have a common `Compile()` method among others so it is natural to think about inheritance here. The package base class cannot be mapped since we want instances of both derived classes to exist in the DB.

But my grasp on EF breaks down when trying to consolidate inheritance with the TPT approach. I do not have control over changing from TPT to another approach. I wonder if EF can be instructed to treat specific scenarios differently. Can an entity class be derived from a non-entity class and how?